# Regex to match everything after double character occurrence

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use Regex to match everything after the double occurrence of an underscore in the following string: `ABCD__A123`. My desired output would be `A123`.

I currently have `/__(.+)/` which produces an output that includes the double underscore. I've searched all over SO and Google for answers with no luck!

Comment: Oh, you have not searched for a *positive lookbehind*, have you? BUT what is the regex flavor (programming language/tool)? Do you really need a lookbehind? You can get the captured value using your pattern.

Comment: I guess DataWeave. Then please read this: [*The `match` operator returns an array of matches that contains the entire matching expression, followed by **all of the capture groups that match the provided regular expression**. In this case `($ match /([A-Z]{2,4})\d*/)[1]` will return the code which will be in the first and only capture  group for those identifiers it matches.*](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/biz/mule/getting-started-with-dataweave-part-4/). So, your regex works as you need, you just need to access the `[1]` value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes DataWeave, thank you for your response.

Comment: I see, but the answer accepted and the fact that you did not provide the regex flavor make your question a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try positive lookbehind like this.

**Regex:** `(?<=__).+`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kO9qA4/1)**